# How to change x,y in plt to lon, lat in cartopy?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

[image]
I want to change x, y to lon, lat (Picture below yellow marker) when I click some point in map and get x, y.
How can I change it? Help me please...

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy

def mouse_click(event):
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print(x, y)

proj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=125, central_latitude=35, false_easting=400000,false_northing=400000,
                                 standard_parallels=(46, 49))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16.535433, 11.692913))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=proj)
ax.set_extent((79, 156, 10, 66))
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=False, linewidth=0.2,color='black', alpha=0.5,
                  linestyle=(3, (20, 5)), xlocs=np.arange(-180, 200, 10), x_inline=False, y_inline=False)
                  #xlabel_style = {'rotation': 0},ylabel_style = {'rotation': 0})

ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', alpha=1, linewidth=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, alpha=1,linewidth=0.5)  
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAKES, alpha=0.4)  
plt.connect('button_press_event', mouse_click)
plt.show()
```

I tried to find about it but It's hard to understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I found some way.
Change the projection.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, facecolor='black')
ax.set_global()
```

In LambertConformal,x,y is different with lon,lat. But in PlateCarree, they are same.

Comment: that's because PlateCarree is just another name for lon/lat projection :-)